# How old is Wonder Woman in Batman Vs Superman?

Tags: dc, dc-extended-universe, batman-v-superman-dawn-of-justice

In Batman vs Superman we are shown photos of Wonder Women in a photo that was taken in 1918:

[image: "Belgium November 1918"]

[image]

And she still looks the exact same as she did nearly 100 years ago.

### So how old is Wonder Women?

I would prefer answers related to the movie Batman Vs Superman in or out of universe.

Comment: Over a hundred, obvs

Comment: @Valorum, thats the answer I was looking for, did you use a calculator? LOL

Comment: Rumor has it, she is just about 5000 years old. But i could not find any links where Zack Snyder mentions it. http://screenrant.com/batman-v-superman-wonder-woman-age/

Comment: @Vishvesh, I read that too, but cinema blend is saying something else.

Comment: Allegedly the assertion comes from Empire Magazine; http://movieweb.com/batman-v-superman-doomsday-darkseid-wonder-woman-age-explained/

Comment: I do think this question should be postponed until her solo film premieres.

Comment: Tracking down this magazine quote is like pulling teeth.

Comment: @Valorum, I can pull teeth all day!!!

Comment: It makes sense to postpone the question, because her age differs based on the origin story.

Comment: Like... rilly old.

Comment: Never ask a lady her age.

Answer (score 15):

According to the [March 2016 issue of Empire Magazine](https://pocketmags.com/empire-magazine/march-2016) Wonder Woman is over 5000 years old. According to actress Gal Gadot (who portrays Wonder Woman) this *un-agingness* forms a key part of her back story and explains her absence for the past hundred years, that 'man's inhumanity to man' and more specifically the sight of *mechanised warfare* have emotionally overwhelmed her, to the point that she simply withdrew from the superhero biz for a few generations.

> Using Greek mythology as the backbone to her backstory, she was born
> Princess Diana of Themyscira, an Amazonian warrior with superhuman
> strength and athleticism, and a golden lasso. In some comic-book
> strands she is the daughter of Zeus.How all this will be recalibrated
> for the realitydetermined context set up in Man Of Steel remains
> elusive, though Gadot confirms that when it comes to inborn talent,
> her metahuman heals quickly, jumps to heights where she is almost
> flying and can really pack a punch.
>
> **She is also over 5,000 years old.**
> “Because she’s seen it all,” says Gadot, “she has seen what humans can
> do, so it was very hard for her to come back and fight.”
>
> <sub><sup>[Empire Online - Gal Gadot](http://www.empireonline.com/movies/batman-v-superman-dawn-justice/batman-v-superman-wonder-woman-gal-gadot/)</sup></sub>

Comment: @KyloRen - I'm still trying to track down a **direct** quote. I hate it when magazine interviewers do this. Paraphrase something that they could just as easily have transcribed.

Comment: I am satisfied with the answer, but anything extra will be appreciated.

Comment: @KyloRen there is better elaborated answer on the sister site https://movies.stackexchange.com/a/74365/1190 but answer about her age will be disappointing